# Can I run multiple instances at once(simultaneously) with selenium-webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate file uploading.

I'v already wrote a tiny program with the [selenium-webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/) that works.

The problem is, there are thousands of files need to be uploaded, I'd like to run multiple browser instances simultaneously to speed up the automation. So I tried something like this

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    i++;
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('firefox')
            .build();

    // login and upload files......
}
```

I expected this would create 10 browser instances at once, and do the automation simultaneously.

But actually... the above code will creates browser instance 'one by one' which means, it won't create another instance until the previous one finishes.

I'v also tried execute the program in multiple shell instances, that will fire up multiple browser instances for me, but I just don't want to do this...

Comment: just curious, is the code you posted wrapped in an `execute_script` operation in your actual script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you need to create multiple threads instead of looping, then you can start each upload in parallel threads. You are on the right track. You dont need selenium grid to achieve this.

lookup about multithreading. You can start with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865315/threads-in-java)

It's not right you need grid for executing multiple browser sessions. You can invoke multiple browser sessions by just creating multiple driver objects, and managing them. Each session will be separate if you want them to be.

Grid is for scaling as there is a limitation on the no of browser instances you can run keeping your machine performance intact and tests stable. Like more than 5 chrome instances in a single machine. If you want to do more than that then you have to use selenium Grid.

Comment: You don't **need** selenium grid to execute test in parallel but managing 10 instances with grid would be a piece of cake.  Just use the same machine for node and host and point your tests to the hub. Done.

Comment: @Shamik Thank you very much! But how can I create multiple threads in node.js?

Comment: @user2272115 Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/32279574/888070

Ignore the profile part , and see the implementation. In node you dont need multiple threads . The functions are asynchronous, so they wont wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: @user2272115 Did it help ?

Comment: This is a very confusing "correct" answer. The question is tagged with JavaScript but this answer says to look up multithreading - something that is not possible in JavaScript. It also links to a post relating to Java, so I can see where the confusion stems from. Some of this confusion is somewhat resolved in these comments. But those Googling this post in the future I have put the correct specific answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new instance of the WebDriver and it's capabilities for each new browser you want to open.

The following will open Google in five separate instances of Chrome.

```
import * as webdriver from "selenium-webdriver";
import * as Chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

function loadSelenium(){
    let options = new Chrome.Options();
    let capabilities = options.toCapabilities();
    console.log('loading another');
    return new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .withCapabilities(capabilities)
        .build();
}

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let driver = loadSelenium();
    driver.get('http://www.google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the purpose of [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

parallel="methods": TestNG will run all your test methods in separate threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they will respect the order that you specified.

parallel="tests": TestNG will run all the methods in the same  tag in the same thread, but each  tag will be in a separate thread. This allows you to group all your classes that are not thread safe in the same  and guarantee they will all run in the same thread while taking advantage of TestNG using as many threads as possible to run your tests.

parallel="classes": TestNG will run all the methods in the same class in the same thread, but each class will be run in a separate thread.

parallel="instances": TestNG will run all the methods in the same instance in the same thread, but two methods on two different instances will be running in different threads.

Comment: Is TestNg https://testng.org/doc/ Java library? This question was about JavaScript.